# In java 8 using stream API, how to return instance from Map with multiple calculations required

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Suppose there is class like this:

```
class A {

    long sent;
    long received;
    double val; // given as max {(double)sent/someDenominator,(double)received/someDenominator}
}
```

of which there are number of instance references in `Map<String , A>`.

Is it possible in one go, using stream API, to return instance of class A with following properties:

- sent = sum of sent fields from all instances
- received = sum of received fields from all instances in Map
- val = maximum value of val, given all entries where val = max {sent/someDenominator,received/someDenominator}

What would be trivial task using standard for loop and one iteration, i don't have a clue how to achieve with stream API.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain ? i am not going to rage downvote you back...

Comment: Why is `val` a `double` if it's the max of two `long` values? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: i have forgot to include that val is calculated by division by some value(which is derived from key name)

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a custom [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `reduce`:

```
Optional<A> a = map.values()
                   .stream()
                   .reduce((a1, a2) -> new A(a1.sent + a2.sent, a1.received + a2.received, Math.max(a1.val, a2.val)));
```

Answer (score 5):

If your `A` objects are mutable, then more efficient solution is possible which is based on `collect()` method. Add a method to `A` which describes the merging strategy:

```
class A {
    long sent;
    long received;
    double val;

    void merge(A other) {
        sent += other.sent;
        received += other.received;
        val = Math.max(val, other.val);
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
A a = map.values().stream().collect(A::new, A::merge, A::merge);
```

This way you will not have to create intermediate `A` object for every reduction step: single common object will be reused instead.

Comment: This is really useful. I was just thinking of how to skip intermediate object creation.